# Why can I fire and event and handle it before registering to it?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

This confusing code works:

```
let event = new CustomEvent("customEvent", {
    detail: { book: "FullStack Vue " }
});

window.dispatchEvent(event);

window.addEventListener("customEvent", e =>
  console.log("This book is " + e.detail.book)
);
```

The confusing part for me is: At the time I fire the event, I'm not already registered as a listener, right? The event should go somewhere into the void. Or is this some kind of "race condition"? That the event registration gets done before the event is really fired?

Or why shouldn't I "listen" to an event before I actually fire it? I try to make sense out of this simple example.

Comment: When you call `dispatchEvent` it is put in a queue, so you will actually register your listener before the queue is processed.

Answer (score 2):

DOM events happen at the next tick, like calling `setTimeout( fn, 0 )`. 'Event loop' is the keyword if you want to find out in more depth.

Comment: Thanks. If this really is a pattern, I need to dig it.